# Is Rmarkdown supporting multiple captions?

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, caption

I need to insert two captions below each figure and above each table.
One caption will be in polish and the second one in english.
In LaTeX this might be accomplished by `bicaption` package in following way:

```
\usepackage{polski}
 \usepackage[english, polish]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[lang=english]{bicaption}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Einrad}

    \bicaption{Polish caption here with special letters: ĄĆŹŚÓŁ}{English caption just below}

    \label{Fig:FIgBicycle}
\end{figure}
```

Is there any possibility to do the same in Rmarkdown? As I can see there's only one `fig.cap=` available?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to make this work well going from .Rmd to .pdf.  However, I am able to hack a solution going from .Rnw to .pdf.  Modify the `source` hook to change the LaTeX `\caption` to `\bicaption` and use the chunk option `fig.cap = "polish caption}{English caption"`.

Here is an example .Rnw file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[english, polish]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[lang=english]{bicaption}

\title{Bicaptions}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

We will defind a hood to replace the {\tt caption} command with {\tt bicaption}
when the \LaTeX\ is rendered.

<<>>=
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)

hook_source <- knit_hooks$get('source')
knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {                
                   txt <- hook_source(x, options)
                   gsub("\\\\caption", "\\\\bicaption", txt)
                 }) 
@

\blindtext

<<eg_graphic, echo = FALSE, fig.cap = 'Polish caption here with special letters: ĄĆŹŚÓŁ }{English caption just below', fig.align = "center", fig.width = 3, fig.height = 3>>=
ggplot(mtcars) + aes(x = wt, y = mpg) + geom_point()
@

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

And the output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Unfortunately, when I've tried to compile your document, for some reason I do not see any image (although there is no error during compilation). Moreover I noticed, that on your attached print screen, there's only polish name for Figure (Rysunek), but in the next line, there's only caption text, without name 'Figure'. This is ('Rysunek' and in the next line 'Figure') the way how it works in LaTeX.